# How to inject specific JSON data into an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Big Picture: Building a website to organize dinosaurs based on time-period - I've learned how to store JSON data files. It is **accessing** and **injecting** this data that I am having trouble with.

- I'm using a pop-up script that fires when an item on one of the lists is clicked that pops-up to display data about the selected Dino (src: http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/)

looks like this: 
[image: example photo]

- From this image you can see there are a few fields that need to be filled from a list of JSON data - from here I have a few questions:

  1. If there are, say, 100 dinosaurs - what is the most efficient way to store this data? Should I have a separate JSON txt file for each dinosaur's traits?
  2. How can I link each list items such that when they are clicked - they load the proper data - without writing very redundant code?

     - *for example the pop up script fires when the "name_open" class is         added to the HTML element that is clicked - could I do something similar to inject my JSON data?*

stored JSON data is such:

```
[
{
    "name": "T-REX" ,
    "period": "85-65 million years",
    "location": "Montana, USA",
    "discovered": "1902"
}
]
```

within the pop-up  the code is as follows:

```
<h3 id = "d-title"> T-REX </h3>
<img id = "d-photo" src = "#" />
<ul>
    <br>
    <li>Name: <p id = "name"></p></li> <br>
    <li>Period: <p id = "period"></p> </li>               
    <br>
    <li>Location(s): <p id = "location"></p></li>
    <br>
    <li>Discovered in: <p id = "discovered"></p> </li> 
    <br>
</ul>
```

- I have ID'd every item into which I would want to inject code.

So, once again - **how can I inject my data, and what is an efficient way on storing a vast amount of data?**

- i understand that this question is broad, but I would really appreciate some directional advice such as would AJAX be completely necessary to inject this data? Or is there anyway to store multiple dinosaur's data in one JSON text file - I'd assume having to use REGEXPs to sort through the data. The biggest obstacle is how to tie each list item to a specific data point in the JSON array without writing an abundant amount of redundant code.

if it's any use I copy-pasted most of the page data into this fiddle, however can't get the pop-up script to function within it: https://jsfiddle.net/evanbananas/ssgeLpox/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery.getJSON() method!

For ex.:

```
$.getJSON( "stored/test.json", function( data ) {
  $.forEach(data, function(d, i) {
     $('#name').html(d.name);
     $('#period').html(d.period);
     $('#location').html(d.location);
     $('#discovered').html(d.discovered); 
  });
});
```

Comment: So I would need to tie one of these functions to every single dinosaur element, but would just change the data[0] to 1,2,3, etc.. for the specific data I want to use.

Comment: you can user forEach in data object inside the getJSON function
(edited the code example)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use AngularJS. It is really simple to work with JSON data and put each value into any html elements.